# Legacy Widgets in WordPress keeps coming back

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I kept deleting this widgets on my wordpress but the problem is that they keep coming back
[image]

I'm using houzez child theme on wordpress
[image]

I went in the appearance > widget on the left side bar of the wordpress. Then I clicked the widget and chose the triple dot option and selected "Remove Selected Widget"
[image]

Comment: Do not forget to flush/clear the server cache and also keep an eye on CloudFlare to purge the cache so you will be able to see the changes.

Comment: I keep flushing and clearing the server cache using Manage wordpress > flush cache. How to purge the cache on CloudFlare?

Comment: Go to https://dash.cloudflare.com/ > select website > click on Purge Cache (on right sidebar) > click on Purge everything twice.
Note: It will only works if you are using CloudFlare service.